# Definition of פוצע on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work

There seem to be three definitions of the מלאכה of פוצע on Shabbos. If anyone can explain in detail what they are, that would be great. I understand this is a complex question, you really have to understand the process of making clothing. The following is a snippet from קופת הרוכלים, found in the משניות זכר חנוך as an introduction to משניות שבת. I understand the first שיטה. The ראב"ד and the ר"ן I do not understand.
Please only people who know the answer should respond. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Sounds like #2 is cutting the threads off the loom when the weaving is done, and #3 is twisting a snapped thread back together during the weaving. See also: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1411&st=&pgnum=102

Comment: See Chayei Adam, Shabbos chapter 25.

Comment: @shmosel interesting, he seems to say the rambam says it means just finishing the weaving process. thanks

Comment: @Shmuel thank you

Comment: The av melachot are kneading the dough and putting the פצע in the oven; l'masseh spreading the sauce and putting cheese and toppings on it are toldot, though Rabbi Yochanan disagrees